# Accessing a mixed branches folder layout using git-svn

Tags: git-svn

I am trying to use git svn to connect to our company repository. We have a slightly non-standard branches directory. How to access this using git svn has been discussed before, however, we seem to have a slight twist in our branch names that seems to keep me from getting them all.

Let's consider an example svn repo:

```
trunk/
tags/
branches/
    rootbranch/
    tku/subbranch
```

We have branches at the root level of the branches directory. But we have branches in nested folders, as well. The same goes for the tags dir, but I think that is just a second example of the same problem.

If I use *git svn clone file:///tmp/gitsvn/svnrepo git-clone -s*, I get only the root branches, as expected:

```
/tmp/gitsvn/git-clone$ git branch -r
  rootbranch
  tku
  trunk
```

But if I clone using _git svn clone file:///tmp/gitsvn/svnrepo git-clone2 -b branches/*/*_, I get only the sub-branches:

```
/tmp/gitsvn/git-clone2$ git branch -r
  tku/subbranch
```

Is there a way to have both?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone else who stumbles over this: it seems that having both is not possible. Subversion allows a mixed setup of branches, but it is discouraged, and so it seems okay that git does not support this. My solution was to bring all branches to the same level, then forget about the issue and move on. Having only one level of branches seems better anyway.

Comment: The solution from caedwa worked, so it seems that it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

Additional branches can be accessed by adding multiple branches lines to the git-svn config.

In the *.git/config* file, there will be a section similar to the following:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
  url = http://server/svn
  fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
  branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/branches/*
  tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

Simply add another entry for the extra directory of branches. For example:

```
branches = branches/tku/*:refs/remotes/branches/tku/*
```

Then run *git svn fetch* to retrieve the branches from the svn repository.

I believe it's also possible to create this setup when constructing the git repository, using multiple *-b* options to the clone command.

```
git svn clone http://svn.foo.org/project -T trunk -b branches -b branches/tku -t tags
```

Comment: git --version : git version 1.7.9.5 This does not work for me: I've added branches = mobile/android/Android_Client/branches/developmentBranches/*:refs/remotes/developmentBranches/* to .git/config and deleted .git/svn/.metadata then run git svn fetch. No dice: only the original branches show up.

Comment: Strangely, I tried again with the second half of the clause using 'devBranches' instead of the full 'developmentBranches' and it seemed a lot happier - instead of errors about missing versions, it's chugging away. Straaange namespace clash?!

Comment: @android.weasel I had the same problem and worked for me (version 1.7.9 inside cygwin)